# Is it possible to access my WinXP home via VPN

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

I'd like to access folders etc on my home computer, a windows xp home edition operating system. How/Is it possible to set up that machine in such way that I can vpn into it and see its files and folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can install software on both your home computer and the remote computer, a program like [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi) may be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) or a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) client would be easiest.

Comment: Unless he pays for Logmein, there is no file sharing.

Comment: I agree, it was moved here ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a PPTP vpn server on XP. Just go to your network connections and start creating a new connection. Select "Set up an advanced connection" and follow the steps in the wizard. PPTP runs on port 1723 so make sure that port is forwarded to your PC.

Comment: I've done the same on an XP Pro machine - but don't know if this is possible on XP Home.

Comment: this was what I was hoping for but doesn't work on home :(

Answer (score 2):

My internet provider does not allow being a VPN server on my home connection. They block the typical VPN ports.

But I can connect very easy to my home PC using Microsft's [Live Mesh](https://www.mesh.com/Welcome/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Install a VNC server on your home machine with the server port set to 80.
This way your home machine will look like a web server to your office firewall.
You can even set it so that you can access your home machine from a browser.
You will probably need to set a dynamic DNS with, for example, [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/).

If you use an advanced VNC server, such as UltraVNC, you will be able to transfer files.

Answer (score 1):

install **[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)** Host on you home computer and use Teamviewer Portable on a USB stick to access you machine from pretty much anywhere, it's doesn't get much easier.

*Teamviewer is free for personal use.*